# select the body element of only certain pages in the site?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I' like to add a different background image to certain pages - is there a way to adjust the following notation:

```
body {background: url('someimage.jpg');
```

to

```
someselector body:url('somedifferentimage.jpg');
```

perhaps a way to select based on the title or the html doc name?

Answer (score 2):

Normally what you'd do is make a different stylesheet for each page and add the declaration. So just:

```
body {
    background-image: url('somedifferentimage.jpg');
}
```

Linked to by the page you want to override. If that's not possible and a little more progressive enhancement is an option, you could try JavaScript of some ilk:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + document.title + ".jpg')";
```

for example.

Comment: thanks for the feedback for which I'm thankful. It seems excessive to create a new and yet nearly identical sheet for this one simple change though? Are there any other methods?

Comment: @DougFirr: Well, there's the JavaScript, and server-side scripting is also a possibility, but... no. Note that you can link to multiple stylesheets, so you won't be duplicating your entire stylesheet; each page-specific stylesheet would contain only the one rule.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your body tag where you want the custom style.

css:

```
.customBody {
background-image: url('somedifferentimage.jpg');
}
```

html:

```
<body class="customBody">
```

Answer (score 2):

The more commonly-accepted way is to put a class on the body element:

```
<body class="specialpage">
```

And then apply the background only to `<body>`s of that class.

```
body.specialpage { background-image: url(...); }
```